# VS Code ERROR: The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I tried running my Spring boot project when I opened VS code then I saw this error. I have been using Java for some months now and this is the first time I am seeing this error. My previous java projects have stopped running due to this error also. Is there a possible fix to this?[screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnNyy.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. I was able to solve this error with the process below:

1. run java --version in terminal to know your jdk version
2. cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
3. /usr/libexec/java_home -V
4. 

- For Bash:

- - echo 'export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/your-java-17-version' >> ~/.bash_profile
- - source ~/.bash_profile

- For Zsh:
- - echo 'export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/your-java-17-version' >> ~/.zshrc
- - source ~/.zshrc

5. echo $JAVA_HOME
6. Go to your project directory and run: mvn clean install
7. In VSCode, go to Command Palette > Clean Java Language Server Workspace